# Excel: Formula error when value is zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used a formula to create a point system for my class. My formula is below, and it works great except that when C2 is zero, the score still shows "10" when I'd like it to be zero as well. I realize that this is an error in my formula but I can't seem to fix it without excel giving me an error message. Could anyone help me edit this formula to fix it?

(I'm a teacher and I'm just trying to make my life a little easier with excel.)

```
IF(TRIM(C2)="","",IF(C2<6.99,10,IF(AND(C2<=7.99,C2>=7),9,IF(AND(C2<=8.99,C2>=8),8,IF(AND(C2<=9.99,C2>=9),7,IF(AND(C2<=10.99,C2>=10),6,IF(AND(C2<=11.99,C2>=11),5,IF(AND(C2<=12.99,C2>=12),4,IF(AND(C2<=13.99,C2>=13),3,IF(AND(C2<=14.99,C2>=14),2,IF(AND(C2<=15.99,C2>=15),1,IF(AND(C2>=16,C2<=100),0))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

**=IF(C2="","",IF(C2=0,0,MAX(ROUNDUP(MIN(16-C2,10),0),0)))**

Answer (score 2):

your first if statement says if c2 is nothing then its blank. why not make another one that check if its 0

This is untested but try

```
IF(TRIM(C2)="","",IF(TRIM(C2)=0,0,IF(AND(C2<6.99,10,IF(AND(C2<=7.99,C2>=7),9,IF(AND(C2<=8.99,C2>=8),8,IF(AND(C2<=9.99,C2>=9),7,IF(AND(C2<=10.99,C2>=10),6,IF(AND(C2<=11.99,C2>=11),5,IF(AND(C2<=12.99,C2>=12),4,IF(AND(C2<=13.99,C2>=13),3,IF(AND(C2<=14.99,C2>=14),2,IF(AND(C2<=15.99,C2>=15),1,IF(AND(C2>=16,C2<=100),0))))))))))))))
```

Again this is untested but hopefully you see what I am trying to do.

Comment: It just says "The formula you typed contains an error"

Comment: dang k, on the train right now let me look it over and see if i can find something wrong.